# In the Django, get multiple Counts of various conditions

Tags: python, django

I am developing "Admin DashBoard" with Django 2.2

I'd count "Objects" of various conditions from one table and send them to the template.

My code is below..

```py
# model
class User(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at_unix = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    country_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    recommender_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,blank=True, null=True, db_column='recommender_id')
    is_agreement = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    delete_yn = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='n')
    is_sms = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_email = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_push = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)



def index(request):
    # New User
    user_lastweek = User.objects.filter(created_at__gte=last_monday, created_at__lte=last_sunday).count()
    user_thisweek = User.objects.filter(created_at__gte=this_monday, created_at__lte=tomorrow).count()
    user_variation = user_thisweek - user_lastweek
    # User total
    user_total_lastweek = User.objects.filter(created_at__lte=last_sunday).count()
    user_total_thisweek = User.objects.filter(created_at__lte=tomorrow).count()
    user_total_variation = user_total_thisweek - user_total_lastweek

    context = {
    'user_lastweek':user_lastweek,
    ...

    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

I have written only a few of the many conditions.

But my code is causing duplicate query hitting every time.

The result I need is like..

```
1. user_lastweek : 114
2. user_thisweek : 98
3. user_total_lastweek : 1232
4. user_total_thisweek : 1330
```

How is it efficient to render to a template with only one query or fewer queries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

solved it myself..

I should've read more about the Django documentation.

Use .aggregate()

```py
test = User.objects.aggregate(
        last = Count('pk', filter=Q(created_at__lte=last_sunday)),
        this = Count('pk', filter=Q(created_at__lte=tomorrow)),
        last1 = Count('pk', filter=Q(created_at__gte=last_monday, created_at__lte=last_sunday)),
        this1=Count('pk', filter=Q(created_at__gte=this_monday, created_at__lte=tomorrow)),
    )
    print(test)
```

```
{'last': 1011, 'this': 1018, 'last1': 38, 'this1': 1}
```

Comment: I'm trying to run a similar code, but the values i get are the same for all aggregations. I run ```MyModel.objects.aggregate(total = Count('pk'), test = Count('pk', filter=Q(user_id='just_a_fake_id')), group_1 = Count('pk', filter=Q(group_id=1)), group_2 = Count('pk', filter=Q(group_id=2)),
    )``` and i end up with those results: ```{'total': 0, 'test': 47479, 'group_1': 47479, 'group_2': 47479}```.   what can be my problem ? I run with Django version=2.2.3