# Django models - how to properly calculate multiple values with various conditions

Tags: python, django, filter, orm, model

I want to calculate multiple values in a single query on my model. Each metric should have a different filter (or no filters at all). I'm using Django==2.2.3 and a [Djongo](https://www.djongomapper.com/) model.

MyModel columns:

```
user_id  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
group_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

What I try to run, [suggested in another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58108675/5889169), does not work for me.

Query:

```
MyModel.objects.aggregate
    (
        total=Count('user_id'), 
        test=Count('user_id', filter=Q(user_id='just_a_fake_id')),
        group_1_value=Count('user_id', filter=Q(group_id=1)),
        group_2_value=Count('user_id', filter=Q(group_id=2)),     
 )
```

The results: `{'total': 0, 'test': 47479, 'group_1_value': 47479, 'group_2_value': 47479}`, does not make sense - all results (except `total`) returns the same number which is the count of all the records.

What I want to run is query similar to

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) as total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN group_id=1 THEN user_id END) as group_1_value,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN group_id=2 THEN user_id END) as group_2_value
FROM MyModel
```

How do I modify the query in order to get the correct values?

Comment: so what I understand, Django count uses joins, when count multiple things it creates duplicates, you can try using `SubqueryCount` from https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils or maybe try `distinct=True` in Count

Comment: `distinct=True` gives the exact same results. as for `SubqueryCount` it i couldn't implement it properly